# Snackbar in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-snackbar

how can I show the snackbar at the bottom of page? I want to show snackbar when clicked on like. I used snackbar in an item of recycleview (crdLayout) so It has been shown at bottom of each item
here is the code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            itemHolder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(itemHolder.crdLayout, "liked", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)         
                                snackbar1.show();
            }
        });
```

the snackbar each time dont pop up at the bottom of page and instead it comes at bottom of each cardview

Comment: Did one of the answers help you? Or do you need further help?

Comment: Yes. It totally worked. but if I wanted to set an action for snackbar to change the itemholder's picture, how can I do it in my activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Snackbar`, you are giving the parameter as `itemholder.cardLayout`. So the *snackbar* will appear below the card layout. You should give the root view of the page to make it appear on the bottom of the page

There are two ways you can achieve this. One is to pass the `rootview` in the constructor of the `RecyclerViewAdapter` class and pass the argument to the `Snackbar`. Another way is to use a callback method in your `Activity` or `Fragment` class that calls your `RecyclerViewAdapter` class.

For the first method, You just pass the `rootView` of the page as a constructor parameter and pass the argument in the `Snackbar`.

For the second method, You can create an interface in the `RecyclerViewAdapter` class, pass the interface instance as a parameter in the constructor, creating a method in the interface and notifying the method when the item has been clicked. Then you can show the `Snackbar` in your `Activity` class itself. See the code below,

```
public class YourActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.CallbackListener{
     View rootView;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //
        rootView = findViewById(R.id.my_root_view);
        // 
        //
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
        //
        //
     }

     @Override
     public void onItemClicked(){
         Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "liked", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
         snackbar.show();             
     }
}
```

And your RecyclerViewAdapter class will be,

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter {
    CallbackListener listener;
            
    public RecyclerViewAdapter (CallbackListener listener){
         this.listener = listener;
    }
        
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
         itemHolder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             listener.onItemClicked();
            }
     });
    
     public interface CallbackListener{
         void onItemClicked();
     }
}
```

Though first method is so simple, second method gives you more encapsulation, more cleaner code and more control over code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a `CoordinatorLayout` within your existing `Activity` layout.
2. Pass the `CoordinatorLayout` as the first argument of the
   `Snackbar.make()` command.

Thus in the end it should look this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

            itemHolder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final View my_new_view = findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout); //define your CoordinatorLayout
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(myCoordinatorLayout, "liked", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG); //set CoordinatorLayout as first argument
                    snackbar1.show();
                }
            });
```

Your `Snackbar` being shown at the bottom of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show Snackbar for whole screen, **don't** pass `View/ViewGroup/Layout` of parent `Activity/Fragment` to Adapter.

Instead pass `Callback/Listener` to RecyclerView `Adapter` from `Activity/Fragment`. This way when item is clicked, you trigger callback. `Activity/Fragment` listening to that callback will get triggered and you can now show Snackbar/Toast/CustomView...